# Cannot find symbol import androidx.room.util.RelationUtil

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room, entity

So I have 2 entity, `ItemEntity` and `Category Entity`.

```kotlin
@Entity(foreignKeys = [
    ForeignKey(
        entity = CategoryEntity::class,
        childColumns = ["categoryId"],
        parentColumns = ["id"]
    )
])
data class ItemEntity (
    @PrimaryKey val id: String,
    val title: String = "",
    val description: String?,
    val priority: Int = 0,
    val createAt: Long = 0L,
    val categoryId: String = ""
        )
```

---

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "category_entity")
data class CategoryEntity (
    @PrimaryKey val id: String,
    val name: String = ""
        )
```

So I'm trying to make one to one relationship with these entities.

```kotlin
data class ItemAndCategoryEntity (
    @Embedded val itemEntity: ItemEntity,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "categoryId",
        entityColumn = "id"
    )
    val categoryEntity: CategoryEntity
    )
```

Then I make this class to make one to one relationship, but then when I'm trying to build there's an error. Here's the error:

### [image]

[image]

The file on image (ItemEntityDAO_impl) is auto generated, and for me this is weird, why generated class that doesn't exists?
Here's my DAO file:

```
@Dao
interface ItemEntityDAO {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ItemEntity")
    fun getAll(): Flow<List<ItemEntity>>

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ItemEntity")
    fun getItemCategory(): Flow<List<ItemAndCategoryEntity>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(itemEntity: ItemEntity)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(itemEntity: ItemEntity)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(itemEntity: ItemEntity)
}
```

And also my `build.gradle` (app)

```kotlin
    //Kotlin Room database
    def room_version = "2.5.1"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
```

I've been tried not to use class `ItemAndCategoryEntity`, the result is work fine, but when I tried to used this class `ItemAndCategoryEntity`, the error happen again. Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 0):

At initial glance, your approach looks solid.  When I try to lookup the RelationUtil dependency, I can't seem to find it.  Any chance you upgraded the Room dependency version recently?

Starting at [Version 2.2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_220_3) there have been massive changes to how relationships are managed between tables.

It is possible that you'll need to clean and rebuild since the autogenerated files are reflecting what could be an obsolete dependency in Room 2.5.1

Comment: so i've tried to clean the build still doesn't work, but later when i tried change `kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"` with the `ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"`, this work well. thanks for the reply

Comment: How did you change from kapt to ksp? I had the same issue and tried to change to ksp using [this guide](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp), but I just got more errors.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have a dependency that depends on room 2.6.0 such as Epoxy 5.1.2, after updating from 5.1.1 to 5.1.2 this exact issue occurred and by downgrading to 5.1.1 it worked fine.

[image: This was its ChangeLog]

You may want to check if there's any dependency that has room as a dependency and check its version.