# Error: "cannot find symbol import androidx.room.util.RelationUtil" when migrating from kapt to ksp

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

When migrating from `kapt` to `ksp` the code is failing when I use `@Relation` to get data from related tables in the Room database.

This is the error message:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.room.util.RelationUtil;
                         ^
  symbol:   class RelationUtil
  location: package androidx.room.util
```

And it occurs in two lines of the autogenerated DAO class:

```
import androidx.room.util.RelationUtil;
```

And:

```
if (_map.size() > RoomDatabase.MAX_BIND_PARAMETER_CNT) {
  RelationUtil.recursiveFetchLongSparseArray(_map, false, (map) -> {
    __fetchRelationshipliturgyTimeAsorgDeiverbumAppDataEntityLiturgyTimeEntity(map);
    return Unit.INSTANCE;
  });
  return;
```

The method of the DAO class is as follows:

```
@Transaction
@Query(todayByDate)
fun getCommentsByDate(theDate: Int): TodayComments
```

And in `TodayComments` I have:

```
data class TodayComments (
    @Embedded
    var today: TodayEntity,

    @Relation(parentColumn = "timeID", entityColumn = "timeID")
    var liturgyTime: LiturgyTimeEntity
)

{
    //...
}
```

If I remove the `@Relation`, the error message disappears. I don't understand why this error occurs in `ksp`, when I was using `kapt` this same code worked without any problem.

I have researched this problem without finding any solution for my case. I only found this question on Stackoverflow:

[Cannot find symbol import androidx.room.util.RelationUtil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76194538/5587982)

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76194538/cannot-find-symbol-import-androidx-room-util-relationutil#comment134369511_76194729), OP says that his solution was to use `ksp`, which confuses me even more, because in my case the error started appearing when I migrated from `kapt` to `ksp`.

I also found [this entry on IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127483380).

In [one of the comments](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127483380#comment27), the following is said regarding `RelationUtil`, which I don't know what it means:

> ...
> Second, the generated code to recursively fetch relationships when exceeding the max binding args amount was moved to runtime helpers
> functions in RelationUtil. This makes them easier to maintain and
> reduces the amount of code generation logic in the writer. However,
> the fetch functions are a bit redundant with each other as they need
> to support various map types, specifically HashMap, LongSparseArray
> and ArrayMap. This also means room-runtime has a new compileOnly
> dependency on androidx.collection to support having these runtime
> helper functions. The function to be use is still determine by
> room-compiler and the availability of androidx.collection types in the
> project's classpath.

#### Edit

In my `build.gradle` file of the App, I have this:

```
//kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2"
ksp 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2'
```

If I use `kapt` as follows:

```
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2"
//ksp 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2'
```

the error disappears.